# Wrong coloring w/ Powerline in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

I setup tmux powerline, and installed all the corresponding fonts.  The problem I am running into now is colors not appearing the same when acting as a background in the hardline.

[image: Color differences shown]

I made sure to set tmux to use 256 color mode

tmux.conf: http://hastebin.com/durehunuge.conf

Any ideas on how to get the colors to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the only way that I was able to fix this was by switching to iTerm2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have trouble with the "arrow" symbols?

If so then you can easily fix that by using the correct symbol.

In your theme file you have some lines that look like that:

```
if patched_font_in_use; then
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_LEFT_BOLD="<U+2B82>"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_LEFT_THIN="<U+2B83>"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_RIGHT_BOLD="<U+2B80>"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_RIGHT_THIN="<U+2B81>"
else
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_LEFT_BOLD="◀"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_LEFT_THIN="❮"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_RIGHT_BOLD="▶"
    TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_RIGHT_THIN="❯"
fi
```

Those are used in your segments, eg:

```
"weather 89 211" \
"date 235 136" \
"time 235 136 ${TMUX_POWERLINE_SEPARATOR_LEFT_THIN}" \
```

which would render on my machine as:

```
  ⮂ ☼ -1°C ⮂ 02.03.2013 ⮃ 10:02
```

As you can see the time arrow is thin without background.